# Mixing default and named exports with Rollup

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I am writing a [Bluetooth library for Node.js](https://github.com/LukasBombach/sblendid/) using TypeScript and Rollup. I want to enable users to import my libraries components in these ways

```
import Sblendid from "@sblendid/sblendid";
import Sblendid, { Peripheral } from "@sblendid/sblendid";

const Sblendid = require("@sblendid/sblendid");
const { Peripheral } = require("@sblendid/sblendid");
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
root
 ∟ rollup.config.ts
 ∟ src
    ∟ index.ts
    ∟ sblendid.ts
    ∟ peripheral.ts
```

And the according code is this:

**`index.ts`**

```
export {
  default,
} from "./sblendid";

export {
  default as Peripheral,
} from "./peripheral";
```

**`sblendid.ts`**

```
export default class Sblendid {}
```

**`peripheral.ts`**

```
export default class Peripheral {}
```

I am bundling everything with Rollup and my entire config is this:

```
import typescript from "typescript";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import typescriptPlugin from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import autoExternal from "rollup-plugin-auto-external";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import pkg from "./package.json";

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: "es",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    autoExternal(),
    resolve({ preferBuiltins: true }),
    commonjs(),
    typescriptPlugin({ typescript, objectHashIgnoreUnknownHack: true }),
    terser()
  ]
};
```

You can find the entire code here

https://github.com/LukasBombach/sblendid/tree/master/packages/sblendid

Now, this setup does not work. Rollup tells me

> ```
> $ rollup -c rollup.config.ts
>
> src/index.ts → dist/index.cjs.js, dist/index.es.js...
> (!) Mixing named and default exports
> Consumers of your bundle will have to use bundle['default'] to access the default export, which may not be what you want. Use `output.exports: 'named'` to disable this warning
> ```

which is true. This

```
const Sblendid = require("@sblendid/sblendid");
```

simply does not work. What I have to do is this:

```
const Sblendid = require("@sblendid/sblendid").default;
```

I can fix this behavior by ***not*** mixing named ad default exports, ok, but then I lose the ability to do this:

```
import Sblendid, { Peripheral } from "@sblendid/sblendid";
```

So I am wondering. Is there *any* way, maybe using multiple bundles, I can achieve having users be able to do both:

```
// This
import Sblendid from "@sblendid/sblendid";
import Sblendid, { Peripheral } from "@sblendid/sblendid";

// And this
const Sblendid = require("@sblendid/sblendid");
const { Peripheral } = require("@sblendid/sblendid");
```

Comment: Did you find out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you target only nodejs environment you can export like this (index.ts)

```js
import Sblendid from "./sblendid";
import Peripheral from "./peripheral";

Sblendid.Peripheral = Peripheral;
export default Sblendid;
```

Comment: Is this how React does it?

Answer (score 0):

Commonjs does not have the concept of *default* export. When you are able do:

```js
const Splendid = require("@sblendid/sblendid");
const { Peripheral } = require("@sblendid/sblendid");
```

It does mean that

```js
assert.equal(Splendid.Peripheral, Peripheral);
```

That `Peripheral` *is* a property of `Splendid`.

This is basically achieved by

```js
Splendid.Peripheral = /* something */;
module.exports = Splendid;
```

When cjs code is transpiled from esm code (what rollup does) the only choice is to introduce a `default` property on the `exports` object.

If you're not comfortable with adding properties just for the sake of exporting, add a snipped like this to your docs.

```js
const { default: Splendid, Peripheral } = require('...');
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by patching rollup.

https://github.com/avisek/rollup-patch-seamless-default-export

```js
// Default export
const lib = require('your-library')
lib('Hello') // <-- instead of using `.default` property

// Named exports
const { namedExport1, namedExport2 } = lib

// One liner syntex. This is also supported.
const { default: defaultExport, namedExport1, namedExport2 } = require('your-library')
```